# Warning: resolving Func by linking to Func@##

Tags: c++

I'm building a DLL with the following:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall DrawMouse(int X, int Y, int R, int G, int B)
{
    Buffer.SetMouse(X, Y, R, G, B);
}
```

Then in a .def file I added:

```
LIBRARY Test
;DESCRIPTION "Test Definition File"
EXPORTS

DrawMouse;
```

Then when I compile, I add the linker options:

```
-static
-static-libstdc++
-static-libgcc
-Wl,--kill-at -d --input-def src\Test.def
-m32
```

And the output is:

> Warning: Resolving _DrawMouse by linking to _DrawMouse@24

Why? Why does it warn me about resolving and how can I get rid of it? For a large amount of exports, I get a large amount of warning..

**Small Example:**

Main.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>

class Input
{
    public:
        void SetMouse(int X, int Y, int R, int G, int B)
        {
            /**Dummy Example**/
        }
};



Input Buffer;
extern "C" void __stdcall SetMouse2(int X, int Y, int R, int G, int B)
{
    /**Dummy Non-Class Example**/
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall DrawMouse(int X, int Y, int R, int G, int B)
{
    Buffer.SetMouse(X, Y, R, G, B);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall DrawMouse2(int X, int Y, int R, int G, int B)
{
    SetMouse2(X, Y, R, G, B);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            DrawMouse(100, 100, 1, 1, 1);
            DrawMouse2(100, 100, 1, 1, 1);
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Test.def:

```
LIBRARY Test
;DESCRIPTION "Test Definition File"
EXPORTS

DrawMouse;
DrawMouse2;
```

Compiler Log:

```
-------------- Clean: Release in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "Test - Release"

-------------- Build: Release in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -O2  -Wall -m32 -DBUILD_DLL  -std=c++11    -c C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\Test\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -shared -Wl,--output-def=bin\Release\libTest.def -Wl,--out-implib=bin\Release\libTest.a -Wl,--dll  obj\Release\main.o   -o bin\Release\Test.dll -s -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,--kill-at -d --input-def Test.def -m32  -luser32 

Warning: resolving _DrawMouse by linking to _DrawMouse@20
Warning: resolving _DrawMouse2 by linking to _DrawMouse2@20
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups

Output size is 32.50 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 2 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

NOTE: --disable-stdcall-fixup does NOT work. Which is why I am asking how to fix this and get rid of these warnings as well as what causes them.

**EDIT:**

Command line with the fixups as requested:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -O2  -Wall -m32 -DBUILD_DLL  -std=c++11    -c C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\Test\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -shared -Wl,--output-def=bin\Release\libTest.def -Wl,--out-implib=bin\Release\libTest.a -Wl,--dll  obj\Release\main.o   -o bin\Release\Test.dll -s -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,--kill-at -d --input-def Test.def -m32 --disable-stdcall-fixup  -luser32
```

Also tried:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -O2  -Wall -m32 -DBUILD_DLL  -std=c++11    -c C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\Test\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -shared -Wl,--output-def=bin\Release\libTest.def -Wl,--out-implib=bin\Release\libTest.a -Wl,--dll  obj\Release\main.o   -o bin\Release\Test.dll -s -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,--kill-at -d --input-def Test.def -m32 --enable-stdcall-fixup  -luser32
```

Neither works.

Comment: What does your source code that calls DrawMouse look like?

Comment: In particular, the header file that declares it...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I updated my post with a sample example as well as compiler log with commands.

Comment: Did you try `--enable-stdcall-fixup` as it tells you to - it says that "disable" doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Yes sir. I tried both. It makes no difference at all. Still gives the warning.

Comment: Can you post the actual command-line where you use this?

Comment: Also added to the OP. JUst updated it with your request.

Comment: Try `-Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup`

Comment: :o That worked! Wow.. Thank you! Still wonder why it happens but that certain helped a lot! What's weird is that both: `-Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup` and `-Wl,--disable-stdcall-fixup` works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply either `--enable-stdcall-fixup` to the linker (which fixes up the problem automatically). When using with `gcc` or `g++`, this means `-Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup`.

For details of these options, check section 2.1.1 of [Gnu Linker options](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/ld/Options.html).